# Как добавить в автозагрузку службу через systemctl enable, если сервис является символьной ссылкой?

Tags: linux, systemd

У меня есть обычный сервис на `systemd`.
Находится здесь `/etc/systemd/system/my-service@.service`

Мне необходимо запускать этот сервис при старте системы.
Я делаю этот так: `systemctl enable my-service@first-service`

после чего, линукс создает некоторые символьные ссылки, и все работает как надо.

Сейчас возникла необходимость, вынести файл `my-service@.service` в другую папку, чтобы этот файл попал под версионный контроль вместе со всем проектом.

Для этого я просто переместил файл `my-service@.service` в нужную мне папку, и `systemctl enable my-service@first-service` сделал симпольной ссылок на файл, который лежит в папке моего проекта.

Про продолжает работать, через `systemctl` можно управлять запуском, остановкой сервиса, но при попытке добавить в автозагрузку, пишу `systemctl enable my-service@first-service` и в ответ ошибка, systemctl ругается, и говорит, что слишком много символьных ссылок. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать? Какие есть варианты решения?

Comment: с помощью `ls -l` опиши, что-где лежит и что-куда ссылается — на словах с одной стороны не понятно, а с другой им доверия куда меньше чем выводу команд... подозреваю, что ты где-то создал цикл из симлинков...

Comment: Поддержу @Fat-Zer. Как ещё один из вариантов - хардлинк. Есть ограничения и не очень красиво архитектурно (имхо), но как запасной вариант - вполне сойдёт.